# Changing Default gmail client on a computer

Tags: windows-8.1

When I go to my Gmail, my daughter's account always shows up instead of mine.  How can I change it so my account will show by default instead of her's?

Comment: Its not clear what your question is.  Gmail is a web application it doesn't have a client.

Comment: Whatever you're using for e-mail, your daughter needs a separate account, so that your settings and hers will be independent. You also need the discipline of always logging off whenever you leave the computer.

Answer (score 1):

1)  To begin, go to her gmail account (the inbox).

2)  Next go up and click on her profile picture.  That should pop up a little box that shows her name, picture, and a button labeled "Add Account" and "sign out".  Click on "sign out".

3)  Now log back into Gmail as **yourself**.

4)  Once in Gmail, go up to your profile picture and click it again.

5)  When the box pops up, click on "Add Account".

6)  Now sign her in.

7)  That should have happened in a new tab, so go back to your inbox, and refresh the page.  (not Gmail's refresh button, but the full browser page)

8)  After it refreshes, click on you profile picture.  As you can see, it shows you above, and then it will have her below.  You can exit out at this point.

Now that you have done that, you will always be the default account when you pull up the browser.  If she wants to use her account, she will just click on your picture, and go down and select her name from the popup box.

NOTE:  In order for this to stay, **she cannot log out.**  If she does that, it will undo this work that we just did.

Good luck!  If you have any questions, feel free to ask!